# Applescript POSIX "Can't make file FILE_PATH into type file" (-1700)

Tags: applescript

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"/Users/NAME/FILENAME\""
```

I have the above AppleScript command to change the desktop background however when running I get the error:

```
execution error: Finder got an error: Can't make file "Macintosh HD:Users:NAME:FILENAME" into type file. (-1700)
```

I'm very inexperienced with AppleScript so all the ideas I've tried to fix it have not worked.

The original script is taken from the internet and seemed to work for others but not me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I bet there's no file under "/Users/NAME/FILENAME"

Comment: Your comment lead me to the solution.  The file was called .wallpaper and apparently that was causing the error.  I've renamed with file to wallpaper and the command now works.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript seems does not see hedden files (with lead point ".") until make hidden visible with cmd+shift+.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).